# ERROR: Could not build wheels for fairseq, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python, pip

pip install fairseq

```
 [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for fairseq
Failed to build fairseq
ERROR: Could not build wheels for fairseq, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

python version 3.8.0

Comment: Please [edit] and show the full text of the error.

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-sdk/

Install the lastest SDK. It work for me.