# ERROR: Could not build wheels for fasttext, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python, python-wheel, fasttext

I'm trying to install `fasttext` using `pip install fasttext` in python 3.11.4 but I'm running into trouble when building wheels. The error reads as follows:

```
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.37.32822\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for fasttext
  Running setup.py clean for fasttext
Failed to build fasttext
ERROR: Could not build wheels for fasttext, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I've searched the web and most hits indicated that the error has something to do with the build tools of visual studio (which the error above also indicated). I've installed/updated all my build tools and I've also installed the latest SDK as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75927836/error-could-not-build-wheels-for-fairseq-which-is-required-to-install-pyprojec), but the error persists.

Has anyone solved this problem before and can share any potential solution?

Comment: https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/issues/1343#issuecomment-1646580169 , https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/issues/1343#issuecomment-1662345725

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `pip install fasttext-wheel` instead solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

Some have reported managing to compile Facebook's `fasttext` package on Windows, and perhaps the issues mentioned in @phd's comment will have some tips that work for you.

But note that the project's official homepage at https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText only says "Generally, fastText builds on modern Mac OS and Linux distributions" – with no mention of official Windows support.

So, other than using a workaround, some options could include:

- switching OSes (which may help with other packages that may be better-supported off of Windows)
- using an alternative FastText implementation, such as that in the `gensim` package - which matches the core fasttext word-modeling (& even has some additional options) but misses some things in Facebook's implementation (mainly the `supervised` mode & word n-grams).